# How do I convert a date before saving it to the database in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to have a date field on one of my models with bootstrap datepicker. I want to format of the date to display as MM/DD/YYYY after a user selects it. the problem is that this date format is not correct for my database (YYYY/MM/DD) and I need to format it before I save it.

In my model I have created a setter method

```
def start_date=(val)
   Date.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%d')
end
```

When I enter a date in my form such as 9/23/2014, I get an error saying invalid date.

What am I doing wrong?

my params

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"***",
 "event"=>{"start_date"=>"09/24/2014",
 "user_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"
 }
```

**edit**

So after changing my method a bit

```
def start_date=(val)
    Date.strptime(val, "%m/%d/%Y") if val.present?
end
```

I no longer get the "invalid Date" error. However, now there are no dates being saved into the record. I've tried

```
def start_date=(val)
    @start_date = Date.strptime(val, "%m/%d/%Y") if val.present?
  end
```

As suggested by @animatedgif , but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

So I figured out the best way to do this (I think :P).

I had to add a write_attribute() to my setter for it to save.

```
def start_date=(val)
    date = Date.strptime(val, "%m/%d/%Y") if val.present?
    write_attribute(:start_date, date)
end
```

This sets my MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD then saves it to the database.

Comment: I like your solution, I might end up using your approach in my code to eliminate the extra instance variable.

Comment: Sweet, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was by introducing a string version of my date field (start_date_str in your case), and using it in my views. I also have a getter and setter for the new instance variable, which wraps the conversions and setting of the actual date field values.

Don't forget to add start_date_str to attr_accessible in Rails 3 or in your white list in Rails 4.

```
  def start_date_str
    @start_date_str || start_date.to_s
  end

  def start_date_str=(value)
    @start_date_str = value
    self.start_date = Date.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think I found a better way for my use case in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning something and not actually setting anything.

```
def start_date=(val)
    @start_date = Date.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%d')
end
```